# how to change the default gear icon look in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, jsom, branding, settings

In the top right corner near the ribbon there have a setting icon in SharePoint 2013. I need to change the Gear icon image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the icon using the following small jQuery code

```
$( document).ready(function() {
         $('.ms-siteactions-imgspan  > img').attr('src','url_Of_your_image');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Siva, I added the code to external js file and linked it to master page Its Working, great

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using CSS. Check this out : [Switch out the SharePoint 2013 Site Actions gear icon](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/07/switch-out-site-actions-gear/)